# sentinel - prevent specific slaves being promoted

Tags: redis, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I have a setup: 3 sentinels, 1 redis master M1, 2 redis slave S1, S2. I don't want S2 being promoted to master when M1 down. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set S2's [slave-priority](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#slaves-priority) to `0`, so that it is never promoted to master